# That was to this, Hyperion to a satyr

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, shakespeare

Here's from *Hamlet*, Act 1, Scene 2.

> But two months dead!--nay, not so much, not two:
>
> So excellent a king; that was to this,
>
> Hyperion to a satyr;

I think I understand the meaning of these sentences.
However, I'm wondering about the grammatical structure of the sentence
"that was to this, Hyperion to a satyr"

Can "Hyperion to a satyr" be replaced by "what Hyperion was to a satyr"?

Comment: I cannot be too sure, but I believe that *Hyperion to a satyr* simply rephrases *that was to this*; i.e. it's in a sort of full-phrase apposition, so to speak.  It seems that *that* refers to Hamlet's father and *this* to his uncle.

Comment: If Hyperion were a place special to satyrs, or even a god held in special esteem or contempt by satyrs, then "what Hyperion was to a satyr" would be the most obvious interpretation; as it is, however, Hyperion had no special relationships to satyrs, nor vice-versa, so I believe the most common interpretation is "as Hyperion *compares to* a satyr". In other words, Hamlet is describing his father as high and perfect as the god Hyperion, and Claidius as low and wretched and bestial as a satyr.

Comment: Exactly: mathematically it's Hamlet:Claudius::Hyperion:Satyr. But "::" and one of the dots in the fourth ":" have been elliped. "A king that was to this [as] Hyperion [was] to a satyr."

Comment: @StoneyB: Nice description.  It confused me for a moment, though, until I recalled that the late king, Prince Hamlet's father, was also named Hamlet.

Answer (score 3):

If you prefer simile to metaphor (and don't care about the poetry), you can replace "Hyperion to a satyr" with "*As* Hyperion was to a satyr". But neither is grammatically `better'.